# Trying to send get method from html to a database

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

For three days I have been trying to send get method from html to my database and get result(list data by name). It's a flash game site. After I submit data it renders the page without data. I'm trying to get data  and list games by data. I don't know  what is the problem. Probably I'm look at every documents and tutorials half of them not working half of them 
I did not understand (I'm a beginner) :-) I will be happy if someone can help me.
Here is my html including my get method :`

```
<% include ./partials/header %>
      <div class="container">
                             <!-- Get is here -->
        <p>
            <form action="/search" method="GET" class="form-inline">
              <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="search..." class="form-control">
                <input type="submit" value="search" class="btn btn-default">
              </div>
            </form>
          </p>
          <div class="banner">
              <img class="banner" src="image/Banner.jpg" alt="">
          </div>
          <div class="new-game">
                <div class="left"> 
                  </div>
            <div class="games">
              <ul class="games-thumb"> 
                  <%  gamesInfo.forEach(  (game)=>{ %>
                  <li>
                    <a href="/oyun/<%= game._id %>" class="thumbnail">
                      <img src="<%=game.gameImg%>" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <span><%=game.gameName%></span>
                  </li>

                  <% } );                   %>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <br style="clear: left;" />
          </div>
          </div>
        <% include ./partials/footer %>`
```

here is my router

```
              const express          =   require("express"),
              bodyParser             =   require("body-parser"),
              app                    =   express();
              router                 =   express.Router();
              var gameName           =   require("../models/inputGame"); 

              router.get("/oyun/:gameNameId",(req,res)=>{
                gameName.findById(req.params.gameNameId)
                .then((gamesInfo)=>{
                    res.render("showGame",{gamesInfo:gamesInfo});

                })
                .catch((err)=>{
                        console.log("errr errr errrr");
                        console.log(err);
                        res.send(err);
                });
            });
        //////////////////
            router.get("/:gameCategorie",(req,res)=>{
                gameName.find({gameCategorie: req.params.gameCategorie})
                .then((gamesInfo)=>{
                    res.render("category/beceri",{gamesInfo:gamesInfo});
                    return;
                 })
                .catch((err)=>{
                        console.log("errr errr errrr");
                        console.log(err);
                        res.send(err);
                });
            });
//////////////////////////Here is Search get router/////////////////////////
        router.get("/search",(req,res)=>{
           gameName.find({gameName : req.query.search},function(err,gamesInfo){
               if(err){
                   console.log(err);
               }else {
                   res.send("item saved to database");
                res.render("category/beceri",{gamesInfo:gamesInfo});
               }
            });
           });
    module.exports= router;
```

my res.render page (trying list my search result )

```
    <% include ../partials/header %>

<div class="container">

      <div class="banner">
          <img class="banner" src="image/Banner.jpg" alt="">
      </div>
        <div class="new-game">
            <div class="left"> 

              </div>
        <div class="games">
          <ul class="games-thumb"> 
              <% gamesInfo.forEach(  (game)=>{ %>
              <li>
                <a href="/oyun/<%= game._id %>" class="thumbnail">
                  <img src="<%=game.gameImg%>" alt="">
                </a>
                <span><%=game.gameName%></span>
              </li>

              <% } );                   %>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <br style="clear: left;" />
      </div>



    </div>
<% include ../partials/footer %>
```

my mongoose Schema

```
          const express             =   require("express"),
          router                    =   express.Router(),
          mongoose                  =   require("mongoose");


         var gameName = mongoose.Schema({
         gameName: {type:String, required:"bos birakma"},
         gameCategorie: {type:String, required:"bos birakma"},
         gameImg: {type:String, required:"bos birakma"},
         gamePath: {type:String, required:"bos birakma"},
         gameTags: {type:String, required:"bos birakma"},
         editor: {type:String, required:"bos birakma"},
         });
       module.exports=mongoose.model("gameName",gameName);
```

my database json

```
    [
{
"_id": "5aaf99c981db2e1d38c84fb8",
"gameName": "Pac Man",
"gameCategorie": "arcade",
"gameImg": "https://image.ibb.co/f5h4AH/4.jpg",
"gamePath": "yok",
"gameTags": "arkade",
"editor": "sometext",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5aaf9a7281db2e1d38c84fb9",
"gameName": "SuperMario",
"gameCategorie": "yok",
"gameImg": "https://image.ibb.co/c9nRPc/11.jpg",
"gamePath": "yok",
"gameTags": "yok",
"editor": "merhaba",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5aafb3913af3be3c64f78aca",
"gameName": "Winged Bullet",
"gameCategorie": "arcade",
"gameImg": "https://cdn4.kongcdn.com/game_icons/0001/0716/thumb100x75.jpg?i10c=img.resize(width:93)",
"gamePath": "<embed width=\"550\" height=\"400\" base=\"https://external.kongregate-games.com/gamez/0000/6057/live/\" src=\"https://external.kongregate-games.com/gamez/0000/6057/live/embeddable_6057.swf\" type=\"application/x-shockwave-flash\"></embed>",
"gameTags": "sometext",
"editor": "sometext",
"__v": 0
},
{
"_id": "5ab1269939800f0e0ce2efc3",
"gameName": "super mario 2",
"gameCategorie": "yok",
"gameImg": "https://image.ibb.co/c9nRPc/11.jpg",
"gamePath": "sometext",
"gameTags": "sometext",
"editor": "sometext",
"__v": 0
}
]
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: its a flash game site. after i submit data its render the page without data .i trying to get data  and list games by data .

Comment: mean database data

Comment: @AdrianMarica please post your input and output testcases.

Comment: i dont know how to do that :) but almost i solve the problem :) when using post method its working :) like= router.post("/search",(req,res)=>{gameName.find({gameName: req.body.search}) now i just need learn  convert on get method :)