# how can I get this data to router from html

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to send Get data from html . I want to submit the data of input to my router to return something. My code is a simply from :

```
<p>
    <form action="/search" method="GET" class="form-inline">
      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="search" id="search" placeholder="search..." class="form-control">
        <input type="submit" value="search" id="search" class="btn btn-default">
      </div>
    </form>
  </p>
```

and my router

```
    router.get("/search",(req,res)=>{
    gameName.find({gameName: req.body.search})
    .then((gamesInfo)=>{
      ///  res.send('id: ' + req.query.id);
        res.render("search",{gamesInfo:gamesInfo});
     //   console.log(gamesInfo)
        return;

    })
    .catch((err)=>{
            console.log("errr errr errrr");
            console.log(err);
            res.send(err);
    });
});
```

Comment: use POST instead of GET to send data. If you want to use GET, pass data as query parameters /url?search=searchValue

Comment: router.get("/search",(req,res)=>gameName.find({gameName: req.query.search}) like this ?

Comment: are you using express.js ? http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query

Comment: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49433027/trying-to-send-get-method-from-html-to-a-database?noredirect=1#comment85868081_49433027) im already try it, its not working I don't know why . Thanks when i post it its working at least i have progress ..